# Trying to Skip an empty field. Returns null instead

Tags: 2013, javascript

I am trying to pull data from a list, but skip any that are empty. Below is the portion of my JS link that Is having this error:

```
var description = document.createElement("a");
description.innerHTML = item.Description;
var wTitle = document.createElement("div");
wTitle.innerHTML = item.Title;

if (item.URL !=null || item.URL != "") {
   description.setAttribute("href", item.URL);
        }
```

Everything works fine, except the URL field, if left blank returns will return the relative url with a "/null" on the end. If the URL field is populated, it works fine.

Comment: ``console.log(item.URL,typeof item.URL)`` in the DEV console and check what URL is

Comment: Not sure about JS exactly but I know in .NET you'd want to use an `IsNull` function, which returns a boolean indicating whether data exists or not. IIRC the explanation goes something like "You can't test equality to a null value because there's nothing there to test." So in your case something like `if (item.URL.IsNull == false...`

Answer (score 3):

The OR(||) condition should be AND(&&) in like below lines of code:

```
if (item.URL !=null && item.URL != "") {
   description.setAttribute("href", item.URL);
}
```

Otherwise, if item.URL is null, item.URL != "" will be true and it will go inside the if statement.

**EDIT: Including excellent suggestion in Anders' comment**

It would be recommended to use

```
if(!(SP.ScriptHelpers.isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty(item.URL))) {
   description.setAttribute("href", item.URL);
}
```

Comment: Also a function provided by SP that one could use: SP.ScriptHelpers.isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty  , basically the same as the answer, but also check for undefined and saves some typing.

Comment: @AndersAune: That's an excellent suggestion, included in answer.